# C libyaml document-based parsing

Tags: c, parsing, libyaml

I'm trying to code a yaml-formatted configuration file parser using C and libyaml. My Internet searches did not bring me any luck with finding a decent and complete documentation of the API with an operation manual. A tutorial by Andrew Poelstra [here](https://www.wpsoftware.net/andrew/pages/libyaml.html) does not describe the document-based *[with the use of `yaml_parser_load ()`]* parsing method, which looks to me by far more logical and justified than the token-based and the event-based methods.

So currently I'm sticking to the doxygen-generated docs from [yaml.h](https://bitbucket.org/xi/libyaml/src/2b9156756423e967cfd09a61d125d883fca6f4f2/include/yaml.h?at=default), and it really leaves me confused about how do I actually parse something after I load a document into a parser. Specifically I do not get which *stack* do we talk in the definitions of the `yaml_document_s` and `yaml_node_s` structs.

An example from `yaml_node_s.data.mapping`:

```
struct {
    /** The stack of mapping pairs (key, value). */
    struct {
        /** The beginning of the stack. */
        yaml_node_pair_t *start;
        /** The end of the stack. */
        yaml_node_pair_t *end;
        /** The top of the stack. */
        yaml_node_pair_t *top;
    } pairs;
    /** The mapping style. */
    yaml_mapping_style_t style;
} mapping;
```

I've figured out that `*start` (in my case) points to an array of `yaml_node_pair_t`'s, each of which contains a pair of `key` and `value` integers, which are the indices by which the corresponding nodes can be acqured using the `yaml_document_get_node ()` function. The meaning of the `*end` and `*top` pointers and how do I determine boundaries of and iterate a mapping using them remains a mystery to me, since `*end` does not contain the final node pair indices.

I would positively be happy if someone clarified to me at least the *stack* meaning here, or even better provided me with a good documentation and examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know the API in question, but the `struct` definition you present looks like a stack built on top of a linked list.  `start` and `end` would point to the first and last nodes in the list, respectively, whereas `top` would point to either the node on top of the stack or the first open position above it.  This kind of data structure would accommodate a stack whose elements (each a key/value pair) do not necessarily occupy all the allocated elements of the list; one might choose this to reduce the number of allocations and frees by allowing node reuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`start` is the bottom of the stack, `top` is above the top of the stack, and `end` points to the last `yaml_node_pair_t` piece of memory allocated for this stack. I figured this out with some experimentation and looking at the libyaml source. looking at `yaml_document_get_node`, `yaml_document_get_root_node`, and `yaml_document_add_scalar` provide some nice hints. for example:

```
YAML_DECLARE(yaml_node_t *)
yaml_document_get_node(yaml_document_t *document, int index)                                                    
{

    assert(document);   /* Non-NULL document object is expected. */

    if (index > 0 && document->nodes.start + index <= document->nodes.top) {
        return document->nodes.start + index - 1;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

but really I guess it should have been obvious to both of us with just the knowledge of what a stack is. Anyway, you want to iterate starting at `start` stopping before reaching `top` like I've done here in a basic implementation:

http://codepad.org/W7StVSkV

(Not guaranteed to be perfect, but it worked for my test case)

Comment: Yes thanks, I've already figured this all out, but still this is a good and correct answer which should be accepted. I do, by the way, possess the knowledge of what a stack is, yet it was not obvious for me how could it be related here, since stacks do not usually get iterated, not as the part of their interface at least. So I'll think about it as an array, anyway.

Comment: Yeah I figured you probably had by now, but I figured I would write this up in case someone else is trying to figure it out and can't find anything else from searching the web. My comment about the obviousness wasn't meant to be rude, I suppose it's not that obvious. I mostly put that in there because I felt silly for how long I took to figure it out.

Comment: This is really helpful thanks!